# Luckeep ebikes problems

Tags: electric-bike

Anyone know why my ebike would be only going like 8 miles an hour? Or how can I check torque sensor to see what's wrong? It has worked fine since I got it but after last charging it today when I got back on it to ride again I can only get it to run around 8 miles per hour. Any suggestions on what I can check to get this issue fixed??

Comment: If possible, more clarity would help. Is this a motor assist bike, and the motor only provides assistance up to 8 mph? Or is this a bike that provides assistance when the rider is *not* pedaling, and yet it only runs up to 8 mph?

Comment: What's on screen when you're riding ?   If no display, does it have any status lights?

Comment: One guess - a dodgy speed sensing switch. If it's bouncing, and producing double pulses instead of single, it thinks you're going twice as fast as you really are and cuts out at the 15mph limit that's often required by law. This assumes a speed sensor, rather than using the speed from the motor driver electronics; different models use different methods

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you set cruise mode? You can call up the control page and select cruise mode to see if the speed is limited. If this method is not feasible, you can directly contact luckeep’s official email address and their customer service will help you solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Can you provide more details (e g. what steps to take) to do this?  Or a pointer to a manual or online tutorial?